# Change SQL Datetime format

Tags: mysql, sql

My database table column holds a datetime in this format: `2017-05-28 15:30:00`. Can I have like this: `3:30 PM Sun, May 28`? How to convert and display to this format?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this an actual `datetime` column?

Comment: The column has this: 2017-05-28 15:30:00, and I want to display like the second format.

Comment: What is the ***type*** of the column?

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully this is a [`datetime` or `timestamp` column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) and not `text` or `varchar`.

`datetime` and `timestamp` don't store dates as `2017-05-28 15:30:00`. They store them as a number and then format them in something human readable. By default this is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`, but you can make it whatever you like.

[MySQL has various functions for working with `datetime` and `timestamp` columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html). You'll probably want [`date_format`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format). To get `3:30 PM Sun, May 28` you want something like:

```
select date_format(date, '%h:%i %p %a, %M %D')
from ...
```

Alternatively, you can let the client receiving the data do the reformatting.

---

If it's stored as `text` or `varchar` you'll have to first convert that into a `datetime` with [`str_to_date`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) and then format it with `date_format`. This is tedious and error prone and slow, which is why it's much better to store dates as `datetime`.

Comment: select date_format(testcol, '%h:%i %p %a, %M %d') from test.test; worked for me using that format

Comment: @BK435 Ah ha! I overlooked `%a` and didn't notice their time didn't include seconds. Thanks!

Comment: np...You were able to answer the rest way more sufficiently and faster than I was... +1 btw..Still not sure what OP data type is though :-/

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do that, but "how" depends on the language. In PHP you use the date command:

```
date('g:i A D, M j',strtotime($sqldate));
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your datetime is in a datetime column data type and not text or varchar, I used the [date_format](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp) function in the below format:

```
select date_format(testcol, '%h:%i %p %a, %M %d') from test.test;
```

The column testcol has this value in it: *2017-05-28 15:30:00*

The result of the query on that column using above query format was: *03:30 PM Sun, May 28*

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a DATETIME column u can  use DATE_FORMAT to display the date formats listed here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format